# How to hide irrelevant languages in Wikipedia in Firefox

Tags: firefox, wikipedia

Is there any way i can hide irrelevant languages in Wikipedia in Forefox browser? 
I want to hide everything except English and Ukrainian for instance so i do not have to scroll on every page up and down every time i need to switch language of an article.

Edit:
I know there is an extension for Chrome "Wikipedia Hide Languages" which does what i want, i want something similar for Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy to do it with [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/)

Create a new style for the wikipedia.org domain with the following content

```css
  #p-lang > div > ul > li {display:none !important}

  #p-lang > div > ul > li.interwiki-en,
  #p-lang > div > ul > li.interwiki-uk {display:block !important}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. And thanks for indirectly reminding me of Greasemonkey. That's where i actually found the exact solution to the problem.  This Greasemonkey script: [Wikipedia rearrange other languages](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/74163) hides irrelevant languages in Firefox.

Comment: Userscripts.org is dead, if you want to rearrange instead of hiding irrelevant ones, check out [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/913789/145861).

Answer (score 1):

[svick](https://superuser.com/a/595927/145861)'s answer is outdated: `User:Lampak/MyLanguages.js` is not maintained. So I went ahead and created a facelifted version: not using deprecated functions any more and much simpler.

*Note: contrary to the question this solution works in any browser (IE, Chrome, Safari, ...), even on mobile if you're not viewing `m.wikipedia.*`.*

#### Usage

1. Go to your [Appearance settings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Preferences#mw-prefsection-rendering)
2. Click the *Custom JavaScript* link
3. Create or edit the page
4. Copy-paste the code:

   ```
   var prefLangs = ["en", "simple", "hu", "de", "it", "es", "pt", "pl", "sv"];
   var prefClasses = $.map(prefLangs, function(lang) { return '.interwiki-' + lang; });
   var prefElems = $(prefClasses.join(', '));
   prefElems.parent().prepend("<hr>").prepend(prefElems);

   var highlitLangs = ["en", "simple", "hu"];
   var highlitClasses = $.map(highlitLangs, function(lang) { return '.interwiki-' + lang; });
   var highlitElems = $(highlitClasses.join(', '));
   highlitElems.css('font-weight', 'bold');
   ```
5. Change `prefLangs` and `highlitLangs` array to suit your needs
   (they don't need to be related, you can highlight non-moved languages as well)
6. Save and read the **Note:** on the page

*You can alternatively use it with your favorite web-site manipulation tool (Greasemonkey, Tampermonkey), but then it's tied to your current browser. Using the above method installs the script everywhere you're logged in.*

[image: preview of the enhancement]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a [user script to move the languages that are important for me to the top](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Lampak/MyLanguages). This will work for any browser, as long as you are logged in on Wikipedia. But it works only for a specific Wikipedia, if you wanted it to work on multiple Wikipedias, you would need to set it up on each of them.

Comment: That's something in the right direction. Good thing this is a "server-side" tweak and can be used with any browser. Bad thing - it has to be setup on every regional wikipedia separately. That is where i stumbled. I managed to get it working on English language wiki, but i failed to set it up on Russian language wiki.

Maybe it has to do with translations, for instance


`importScript('User:Somebody/script.js')`   requires translation of the word "User" into Russian language.

Comment: @RusI I believe it doesn't require translation, but it does require that the script exists on that wiki. So, if you want to use it on a wiki where it doesn't exist, you need to copy it there.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [Universal Language Selector](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Universal_Language_Selector/Design/Interlanguage_links) lab that you can enable in the [beta features preferences](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Preferences#mw-prefsection-betafeatures).

It says it's working based on your location (Geo-IP), so it may not be as good as other options.